# clearing a link with javascript only works for the first link

Tags: javascript

Found a bit of javascript that clears the link to current page. So far so good. It worked until there were more than one link.

```
/*
CLCP v2.1 Clear Links to Current Page
Jonathan Snook
This code is offered unto the public domain
http://www.snook.ca/jonathan/
*/

window.onload = clearCurrentLink;
setTimeout("clearCurrentLink()",50);
function clearCurrentLink(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i].href == window.location.href.split("#")[0])
            removeNode(a[i]);
}

function removeNode(n){
    if(n.hasChildNodes())
        for(var i=0;i<n.childNodes.length;i++)
            n.parentNode.insertBefore(n.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true),n);
    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
}
```

Thing is I can't figure out why it only clears the first link it finds.

I'm generating pages through node / expresss / jade / stylus. Any other ides on how to eliminate links to the current page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop in clearCurrentLink should go in reverse order.

Comment: is this what you mean? for(var i=0;i>a.length;i--)

Comment: for(var i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)